# Excel::VBA - How to reset the 'OnXXX' macros for worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, event-handling

I have an old workbook (made by someone years ago) with a few worksheets in it. When I open this workbook, Excel complains with messages like 'Cannot find ActivateWorksheet', 'Cannot find DeActivateWorksheet'.
There are no event handlers in the code. I want to avoid getting these messages from Excel but  could not find how to reset them. I checked the OnSheetActivate, OnSheetDeactivate etc properties to see if some macro is assigned but found them to be empty.

Is there any other place where I can check and remove these handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one more place to look: NamedRanges. I found that the worksheet has Names defined with values such as "=ActivateWorksheet", "=DeActivateWorksheet" but these macros were nowhere. When a worksheet is activated, the Names on that sheet is refreshed (or recalculated) and i my case the macro were being called.

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to AddIns - do you have all the necessary AddIns installed?

Comment: OK. The workbook referenced an XLA that I removed but how do I remove these handlers from workbook. I do not want to associate the XLA with the workbook.

Comment: @A9S6, you removed all XLA's but are still getting error messages?

Comment: Yes, I removed the XLA from References list and even deleted the XLA file but the message is still shown